# Study roadmap to write a crypter / backdoor

Tags: professional-education, antivirus, python, assembly

Recently I came across a site called [SecurityTube.net](http://SecurityTube.net), which has a ton of amazing security stuff. I'm following their Python Scripting Expert videos which are totally worth it. I also came across the concept of 'Crypters', which evade antiviruses and can be used for Metasploit payloads.

I decided to ask here because there's a lot of varying opinions like:

1. Python isn't the best language to write a Crypter, as the exe generated is large.
2. VB is the real deal, etc.

I personally feel the best roadmap starts with diving deep into the assembly language videos posted on SecurityTube and graduate to at least the Exploit Research series.

I've some experience with Java (along with some JCE) and PHP i.e. general high level programming being an IT student but low level programming has only recently interested me.

So is my thinking of diving into assembly in parallel with my Python learning the correct pathway? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a crypter, usually you take a certain shellcode and then load it into a script which generates another shellcode which contains an encrypted form of your shellcode. At runtime the shellcode will then be decrypted and run. To generate this encrypted form you will need to either use an existing crypter or create your own. In your python script you then encrypt your shellcode so it's decryptable from your new shellcode (which contains the encrypted shellcode).

I'm an avid Python user, others here use Ruby (in which Metasploit is written btw). In the end you should use the best tool for the job. However this is very diverse depending on your platform. So you should just try a few tools and then decide which is best for you. There is not a single good tool for doing this. (but you will need to learn some assembly if you want to write low level exploits)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lucas.                                 A is the shellcode, B is the script,                     then A + B = C(encrypted shellcode) which will be decrypted at runtime.  So either I can use A (an existing shellcode or write one from scratch) and then add it to B(my custom Python script) to generate C. I hope I got it right.

Comment: Exactly, you should have a look at my blog ( click my name) I did the security tube Linux assembly expert which actually details most of this. It's pretty neat :)

Comment: I had some confusion at first. But later on, I saw your Linux Assembly assignment and I got exactly what you meant!! I came back to reply you, but stackexchange was saying 'comment edits allowed only every 5 minutes'. So I left :)

Comment: If this was useful for you, you can always accept it by clicking the accept mark :)